# Compute returns with multiple lines buy and sell in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compute returns in my `dataframe` Here is an exemple

```
     Type                    Date Open Qty        Price       Amount

7  Bought 2018-06-28 20:47:39 UTC     0.01 667272.13336 6672.7213336
8    Sold 2018-06-28 20:47:48 UTC   0.0078    667514.96  5206.616688
9    Sold 2018-06-28 20:47:48 UTC   0.0022    667514.96  1468.532912
10 Bought 2018-06-28 20:48:17 UTC     0.01 668624.18413 6686.2418413
11   Sold 2018-06-28 20:48:33 UTC    0.005    668424.97   3342.12485
12   Sold 2018-06-28 20:48:35 UTC    0.005    668435.82    3342.1791
13 Bought 2018-06-28 20:48:50 UTC     0.01    667898.67    6678.9867
14   Sold 2018-06-28 20:48:58 UTC     0.01    667881.57    6678.8157
```

for exemple line 7, 8 and 9, the returns of the line 7 to the average price of the line 8 and 9, Same for the line 11, 12 and 13.

Sometimes I can have 3 `bought` and 1 `Sold` or 4 `sold` and 1 `bought`but quantities always match between `bought` and `sold`

Here is a longer dataframe.

```
9    Sold 2018-06-28 20:47:48 UTC     0.0022    667514.96     1468.532912
10 Bought 2018-06-28 20:48:17 UTC       0.01 668624.18413    6686.2418413
11   Sold 2018-06-28 20:48:33 UTC      0.005    668424.97      3342.12485
12   Sold 2018-06-28 20:48:35 UTC      0.005    668435.82       3342.1791
13 Bought 2018-06-28 20:48:50 UTC       0.01    667898.67       6678.9867
14   Sold 2018-06-28 20:48:58 UTC       0.01    667881.57       6678.8157
15 Bought 2018-06-28 20:49:54 UTC       0.01    668941.24       6689.4124
16   Sold 2018-06-28 20:50:01 UTC       0.01    668895.62       6688.9562
17 Bought 2018-06-28 20:50:09 UTC       0.01 668363.00995    6683.6300995
18   Sold 2018-06-28 20:50:16 UTC       0.01    668598.95       6685.9895
19 Bought 2018-06-28 20:50:26 UTC       0.01    668302.02       6683.0202
20   Sold 2018-06-28 20:51:13 UTC       0.01    668048.75       6680.4875
21 Bought 2018-06-28 20:51:21 UTC       0.01    667738.97       6677.3897
22   Sold 2018-06-28 20:51:26 UTC       0.01    667407.38       6674.0738
23 Bought 2018-06-28 20:51:45 UTC       0.01    667202.04       6672.0204
24   Sold 2018-06-28 20:51:51 UTC       0.01    667691.88       6676.9188
25 Bought 2018-06-28 20:51:59 UTC       0.01    667555.03       6675.5503
26   Sold 2018-06-28 20:52:02 UTC       0.01 668399.88746    6683.9988746
27 Bought 2018-06-28 20:53:19 UTC       0.01    669015.02       6690.1502
28   Sold 2018-06-28 20:53:28 UTC       0.01    669273.76       6692.7376
29 Bought 2018-06-28 20:53:42 UTC       0.01 668927.79587    6689.2779587
30   Sold 2018-06-28 20:53:47 UTC       0.01     669060.9        6690.609
31 Bought 2018-06-28 20:53:52 UTC       0.01     668489.0         6684.89
32   Sold 2018-06-28 20:56:04 UTC       0.01    668645.62       6686.4562
33 Bought 2018-06-28 20:56:11 UTC       0.01 668350.04001    6683.5004001
34   Sold 2018-06-28 20:56:15 UTC       0.01    669108.98       6691.0898
35 Bought 2018-06-28 20:57:07 UTC       0.01    669105.02       6691.0502
36   Sold 2018-06-28 20:57:10 UTC       0.01    669413.97       6694.1397
37 Bought 2018-06-28 20:57:13 UTC       0.01 669028.23458    6690.2823458
38   Sold 2018-06-28 20:57:32 UTC       0.01    668769.98       6687.6998
39 Bought 2018-06-28 20:57:58 UTC      0.001    668442.05       668.44205
40 Bought 2018-06-28 20:58:31 UTC      0.009    668602.02      6017.41818
41   Sold 2018-06-28 20:58:35 UTC       0.01    668293.98       6682.9398
42 Bought 2018-06-28 20:59:04 UTC       0.01    668626.02       6686.2602
43   Sold 2018-06-28 20:59:43 UTC       0.01    668892.83       6688.9283
44 Bought 2018-06-28 20:59:54 UTC       0.01    669230.64       6692.3064
45   Sold 2018-06-28 21:02:40 UTC       0.01    668746.96       6687.4696
46 Bought 2018-06-28 21:02:49 UTC       0.01    668019.58       6680.1958
47   Sold 2018-06-28 21:03:43 UTC       0.01    667884.01       6678.8401
50 Bought 2018-06-28 21:08:27 UTC      0.004 666489.20149   2665.95680596
51   Sold 2018-06-28 21:08:33 UTC      0.004    667159.97      2668.63988
52 Bought 2018-06-28 21:09:02 UTC      0.004     666584.0        2666.336
53   Sold 2018-06-28 21:09:08 UTC      0.004    666740.27      2666.96108
54 Bought 2018-06-28 21:09:11 UTC      0.004     666243.0        2664.972
55   Sold 2018-06-28 21:09:35 UTC      0.004    664868.94      2659.47576
56 Bought 2018-06-28 21:09:38 UTC      0.004    664281.02      2657.12408
57   Sold 2018-06-28 21:09:40 UTC      0.004 663341.23067   2653.36492268
58 Bought 2018-06-28 21:09:46 UTC      0.004 663304.22439   2653.21689756
59   Sold 2018-06-28 21:09:51 UTC      0.004    663513.95       2654.0558
60 Bought 2018-06-28 21:10:00 UTC      0.004 662645.73213   2650.58292852
61   Sold 2018-06-28 21:10:03 UTC      0.004 663052.46877   2652.20987508
62 Bought 2018-06-28 21:10:17 UTC      0.004 663231.30528   2652.92522112
63   Sold 2018-06-28 21:10:22 UTC      0.004 662929.97241   2651.71988964
64 Bought 2018-06-28 21:10:25 UTC      0.004    662654.21      2650.61684
65   Sold 2018-06-28 21:10:29 UTC      0.004    662415.95       2649.6638
66 Bought 2018-06-28 21:10:32 UTC 0.00273645    662007.02  1811.549109879
67 Bought 2018-06-28 21:10:34 UTC 0.00126355    661876.02   836.313445071
68   Sold 2018-06-28 21:10:41 UTC      0.004    661164.97      2644.65988
69 Bought 2018-06-28 21:10:45 UTC      0.004    660556.03      2642.22412
70   Sold 2018-06-28 21:10:48 UTC      0.004    660872.98      2643.49192
71 Bought 2018-06-28 21:11:30 UTC      0.004    661167.27      2644.66908
```

If anyone has an idea, thank you

Comment: Are you looking for total returns form the data.frame?

Comment: no partial returns

Comment: Partial returns on what basis? Please update for your expected results.

Comment: for exemple the return of line 10,11,12 here there are 3 lines so I have my by quantity of 0.01 and I buy for 6686.2418 USD then when I sell in line 11 and 12 I have to find the average sell price (0.005  *  668424.97 + 0.005 *  668435.82 ) = 6684.30 so the return in line 12 is 6684.30/6686.24 Then for the 2 next line 13 and 14 it is only '6678.8157/6678.98' and so on until the end

Comment: Do you want to divide or subtract?

Comment: I prefer divide

Comment: I have updated answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to have many outliers which is not possible -> summary(test2$ReturnVal)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  0.0000   0.9997   1.0001   1.3014   1.0005 465.5305

Comment: Thats's why its better to provide expected output. May be if you can provide expected output for even small data.frame then also it will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One can group data on each occurrence of `Bought` and then calculate the sum of difference between `Sold` and "Bought" for each group.

A solution using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Grp = cumsum(Type=="Bought")) %>%
  summarise(Date = first(Date), 
            ReturnVal = sum(Amount[Type=="Sold"]) / sum(Amount[Type=="Bought"])) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   Grp                    Date ReturnVal
# 1   1 2018-06-28 20:47:39 UTC 1.0003639
# 2   2 2018-06-28 20:48:17 UTC 0.9997102
# 3   3 2018-06-28 20:48:50 UTC 0.9999744
```

**Note:** I have chosen to display 1st date along with summarized data. One can opt to include additional columns.

**Data:**

```
df <-read.table(text="
Type                    Date Qty        Price       Amount
Bought '2018-06-28 20:47:39 UTC'     0.01 667272.13336 6672.7213336
Sold '2018-06-28 20:47:48 UTC'   0.0078    667514.96  5206.616688
Sold '2018-06-28 20:47:48 UTC'   0.0022    667514.96  1468.532912
Bought '2018-06-28 20:48:17 UTC'     0.01 668624.18413 6686.2418413
Sold '2018-06-28 20:48:33 UTC'    0.005    668424.97   3342.12485
Sold '2018-06-28 20:48:35 UTC'    0.005    668435.82    3342.1791
Bought '2018-06-28 20:48:50 UTC'     0.01    667898.67    6678.9867
Sold '2018-06-28 20:48:58 UTC'     0.01    667881.57    6678.8157",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```